# how to access XML subnodes using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to use javascript to get information from a xml file loaded into a webpage.

The below given is the xmlfile(a.xml) i am using.

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Step rID="T6">
  <Obj ><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Obj>
  <Details ><![CDATA[]]></Details>
  <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
  <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
  <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="9" >
    <Disp><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Disp>
  </NodeArgs>
</Step>
<Step rID="T7">
  <Obj ><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Obj>
  <Details ><![CDATA[Toral Row get:65534]]></Details>
  <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
  <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
  <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="10" status="Passed" >
    <Disp><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Disp>
  </NodeArgs>
</Step>
```

I want to access nodes under a specific node in xml using java script?
That is i want to access Time node after i access step node.
And the below given is the index.html page to which i want to load the xml data

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Results of  <b>Test cases</b> </p>
    <div id="books"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
  var oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var testcase_Number = 0;
  var endOfTest= 0;
  function reportStatus() {
    if (oXHR.readyState == 4)               // REQUEST COMPLETED.
      showTheList(this.responseXML);      // ALL SET. NOW SHOW XML DATA.
  }

  oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
  oXHR.open("GET", "a.xml", true);      // true = ASYNCHRONOUS REQUEST 
                                   //(DESIRABLE), false = SYNCHRONOUS REQUEST.
  oXHR.send();

  function showTheList(xml) {
    var divBooks = document.getElementById('books');        // THE PARENT DIV.
    var Book_List = xml.getElementsByTagName('Step');       // THE XML TAG NAME.
    var divLeft = document.createElement('div');
    divLeft.className = 'col1';

    for (var i = 0; i < Book_List.length; i++) {
      divLeft.innerHTML=Book_List[i].getChildElementsByTagName("Time")[0].nodeValue;
      divBooks.appendChild(divLeft);
    }
  };
  </script>
</html>
```

In the above code I am trying to access the Time  subnode under the  step node.
and I have used arrays in the above example as the xml page i am using have lots of Step subnodes , and i want to access the Time subnodes under Step for each one of them.

thanks,
Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is my first post in stack over flow.. sorry for any missing informations

Comment: Add some sourcecode. What have you tried?

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa, i have updated my post, please have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, @NIMALKRISHNA . An improvement: use indentation in your sourcecode.

Comment: i  have posted a new question , please have a look at it ,thanks

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa can u have a look at this post?  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250142/how-to-load-an-xml-file-into-a-html-page-using-java-script-and-parse-data-from-i? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option of iterating over the xml nodes directly, employing one of the [XPath processing APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate). It basically suffices to rewrite your `showTheList` function. What follows is a complete standalone solution, however:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script>
        function showTheList() {
            let x_xmlisland = document.getElementById("template_xml");
            let s_xmlsource = x_xmlisland.textContent; 

            // Parse xml. This may beunnecessary depending on the ajax lib used. 
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(s_xmlsource, "application/xml");

            // Obtain the xml node set containing the needed info.
            // In this case, these are the textual contents of all 'Time' elements that are children of a 'Step' node.
            let xpr_time  = xmlDoc.evaluate("//Step/Time/text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            let node_time
              ;

            let divBooks = document.getElementById('books');        // THE PARENT DIV.
// debugger; // uncomment for tracing 
            while ( ( node_time = xpr_time.iterateNext() ) !== null ) { // iterate over xml nodes
                let divLeft = document.createElement('div');
                divLeft.className = 'col1';
                divLeft.innerHTML = node_time.textContent;  // The xpath expression references the 'text()' function which provides a text node. String must still be extracted. 
                divBooks.appendChild(divLeft);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="showTheList()">
        <script type="text/xml" id="template_xml"><?xml version="1.0"?>
<Steps>
    <Step rID="T6">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="9" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
    <Step rID="T7">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[Toral Row get:65534]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:27]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="10" status="Passed" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
</Steps>
        </script>
        <p>Results of  <b>Test cases</b> </p>
        <div id="books"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code has been tested.

**Note**

The sample xml provided in the question is not well-formed since it lacksa unique root element. The solution would still work but only consider the first `Step`element.

**Update**

To allow for xml from an external source, the ajax code needs to be reintroduced:

```
function getData() {
    let oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    oXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oXHR.readyState == 4 && oXHR.status == 200) {
            showTheList(oXHR);
        }
    };
    oXHR.open("GET", "state_data.xml", true); // ...or whatever else
    oXHR.send();
} // getData
```

Lacking local data, it makes no longer sense to register `showTheList` as an onLoad handler.

```
<body onLoad="getData()">
```

Comment: Hi collapsar, thanks for the help. I tried the above function but it is not displaying the time value. checking what went wrong now.. :(

Comment: @NIMALKRISHNA Your xml sample lacks a unique root element, which basically blots out allbut the first `Step` elements. I introduced an artificial `Steps` element in the revised solution. The solution works as-is. Note that I have also changed the time stamp in the second `Time` element to disambiguate the output.

Comment: Hi @collapsar , is there a way to add this xml file as a  seperate file instead of puting it in html ?because i need to display the informations from an xml file which keeps on changing.

Comment: @Nimalkrishna I've complemented the answer