# How to load an xml file into a html page using java script and parse data from it using Xpath

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Hi i am using java script to extract data from xml file.

The below given is my index.html

**index.html**

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Report</title>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script>
            function showTheList() {
                let x_xmlisland = document.getElementById("template_xml");
                let s_xmlsource = x_xmlisland.textContent; 

                // Parse xml. This may beunnecessary depending on the ajax lib used. 
                let parser = new DOMParser();
                let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(s_xmlsource, "application/xml");

                // Obtain the xml node set containing the needed info.
                // In this case, these are the textual contents of all 'Time' elements that are children of a 'Step' node.
                let xpr_time  = xmlDoc.evaluate("//Step/Time/text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
                let node_time
                  ;

                let divBooks = document.getElementById('books');        // THE PARENT DIV.
    // debugger; // uncomment for tracing 
                while ( ( node_time = xpr_time.iterateNext() ) !== null ) { // iterate over xml nodes
                    let divLeft = document.createElement('div');
                    divLeft.className = 'col1';
                    divLeft.innerHTML = node_time.textContent;  // The xpath expression references the 'text()' function which provides a text node. String must still be extracted. 
                    divBooks.appendChild(divLeft);
                }
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onLoad="showTheList()">
            <script type="text/xml" id="template_xml"><?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Steps>
        <Step rID="T6">
            <Obj ><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Obj>
            <Details ><![CDATA[]]></Details>
            <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
            <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
            <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="9" >
                <Disp><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Disp>
            </NodeArgs>
        </Step>
        <Step rID="T7">
            <Obj ><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Obj>
            <Details ><![CDATA[Toral Row get:65534]]></Details>
            <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:27]]></Time>
            <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
            <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="10" status="Passed" >
                <Disp><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Disp>
            </NodeArgs>
        </Step>
    </Steps>
            </script>
            <p>Results of  <b>Test cases</b> </p>
            <div id="books"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here the time data is extracted and displayed.
But i dont want the xml data to be part of html code, instead i want the xml data to be in a seperate file , say a.xml, and load this xml data to the html page and parse the time data from it.

can anyone help me with this? for the project i am working on i want the time data to be parsed using xpath preferably.

**note**
    This post is a continuation of [This stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199722/how-to-access-xml-subnodes-using-javascript?noredirect=1#comment89426296_51199722) , and i would like to thank @collapsar for the code above.

**This is what i have tried , but it is not parsing the time value correctly**

```
    **index.html**


<html>
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script>
     var oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    var testcase_Number = 0;
    var endOfTest= 0;
    function reportStatus() {
        if (oXHR.readyState == 4)               // REQUEST COMPLETED.
        {
            showTheList(this.responseXML);      // ALL SET. NOW SHOW XML DATA.
            }
    }

    oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
    oXHR.open("GET", "a.xml", true);      // true = ASYNCHRONOUS REQUEST (DESIRABLE), false = SYNCHRONOUS REQUEST.
    oXHR.send();
        function showTheList(ab) {
            //let x_xmlisland = document.getElementById("template_xml");
           let s_xmlsource = ab.textContent; 

            // Parse xml. This may beunnecessary depending on the ajax lib used. 
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(s_xmlsource, "application/xml");

            // Obtain the xml node set containing the needed info.
            // In this case, these are the textual contents of all 'Time' elements that are children of a 'Step' node.
            let xpr_time  = xmlDoc.evaluate("//Step/Time/text()", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            let node_time
              ;

            let divBooks = document.getElementById('books');        // THE PARENT DIV.
// debugger; // uncomment for tracing 
          while ( ( node_time = xpr_time.iterateNext() ) !== null ) { // iterate over xml nodes
                let divLeft = document.createElement('div');
                divLeft.className = 'col1';
                divLeft.innerHTML = xpr_time.textContent;  // The xpath expression references the 'text()' function which provides a text node. String must still be extracted. 
                divBooks.appendChild(divLeft);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >

        <p>Results of  <b>Test cases</b> </p>
        <div id="books"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**a.xml**

```
<Steps>
    <Step rID="T6">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="9" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
    <Step rID="T7">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[Toral Row get:65534]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:27]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="10" status="Passed" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
</Steps>
```

I have managed to load xml file into html page and load data in the past, but i have never worked with xpath for extracting data from xml file,
which is neccessary for the project i am working with, so  the first index.html successfully extract time data from the xml file using xpath, but i cant move the xml data to a whole seperate file from that code

Any help will come handy,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make a HTTP GET request to the file using whatever method you find most suitable (fetch, $.get, axios.get, ...) and parse what comes back

Comment: @Luca  , edited the post now, please have a look at it,Thanks

Comment: You arent accepting any arguments in the `showTheList` function ;-)

Comment: @Luca, thanks for that!  but still it is not outputting time value, it seems that xpr_time has null value in it, and obviously xpath parsing didnt happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help,
Finally was able to do it..below given is the answer to any folks who come here in desperation.
Thanks

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(xhttp.responseXML);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "a.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 

function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";
    path = "//Step/Time"
    if (xml.evaluate) {
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        } 
    // Code For Internet Explorer
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
        nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            txt += nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Steps>
    <Step rID="T6">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:26]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="9" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[Get Data Table - Passed]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
    <Step rID="T7">
        <Obj ><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Obj>
        <Details ><![CDATA[Toral Row get:65534]]></Details>
        <Time><![CDATA[7/5/2018 - 13:16:27]]></Time>
        <TimeTick>1530810986</TimeTick>
        <NodeArgs eType="User" icon="5" nRep="10" status="Passed" >
            <Disp><![CDATA[GetDataTable - Successful]]></Disp>
        </NodeArgs>
    </Step>
</Steps>
```